# How can we Dyanamic Images Produced from Database using Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, image-caching

**Problem:**

I could not find a proper/working info googling about caching dyanamic images, as per my requirement.

I am using Zend Framework and url of the images looks like http://localhost/media/image/id/1120. The images are stored in the database.

Is there any way I can cache my images.

**One of the Resouce Looked at:**
http://dtbaker.com.au/random-bits/how-to-cache-images-generated-by-php.html

This is the closet I could get and the images are cached in this website but can't make it work on situation like mine.

A help would be great.

Comment: Arent they already cached when they are stored in a database?

Comment: In your link we just see a client-side caching. And in the @vascowhite answer -- mostly server-side. But I hope in zend_cache we have both client/server caching.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Zend Framework, then your first port of call for caching anything should be [Zend_Cache](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.cache.html).

Having said that, caching images is probably the easiest caching problem to solve as it is just a matter of saving a local copy of any image to your server after it is generated and checking for a local copy before running the code that generates it.

Something like:-

```
if(file_exists(image12345.png){
    serve cached file;
} else {
    generate new file;
    save new file to image12345.png;
    serve cached file;
}
```

Looking at your user name you should be able to work out real, working code for yoursel(f)(ves).

Comment: @vascowhite thanks. It's ver useful what you've said. I'm doing the similar way at the moment as well. I wanted to know if there is a wayI can cache in client side.

Comment: TBH I'm not sure, I think caching on the client side is under the control of the client. Most browsers will cache images anyway, so I wouldn't get too worried about that.